# .nextElementSibling no funciona correctamente en JS. Por que?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Intento realizar un formulario animado con HTML CSS y JS. Todo parece estar bien exceptuando el código de JS que no parece añadir una clase de CSS cuando debería hacerlo y no encuentro el error.
Este es el código de JS.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('formulario_input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    if(this.value.length>=1) {
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('fijar');
    } else {
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('fijar');
    }
  });
}
```

Todos los estilos de CSS se ven bien incluso la transición de cuando estas rellenando el formulario. Aquí dejo algún estilo.

```
.formulario_label {
    padding-left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -85px;
    z-index: -20;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
```

Por lo que lo único que puede estar dando algún fallo tiene que ser el código de JS. Y por lo que creo debería de ser con el .nextElementSibling por que al intentar imprimir el .parentNode me da undefined pero no entiendo el por que si este es el HTML.

```
<form action="" class="formulario">
            <h1 class="formulario_titulo">Contáctenos</h1>
            <input type="text" class="formulario_input">
                <label for="" class="formulario_label">Nombres</label>
            <input type="text" class="formulario_input">
                <label for="" class="formulario_label">Correo</label>
```

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: recien lo probe y anda bien capaz ajustando alguna cosita , podrias poner el estilo que tenes en la clase .fijar, a mi me corrio  poniendo algo en esa clase y se agrega y remueve fijar tambien

Comment: ```
.fijar {
    margin-top: -135px;
  }
```
Este es el estilo de la clase fijar, probé a añadir alguna cosa mas pero tampoco funciona... Que pusiste tu en esa clase ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el `nextElementSibling` funciona bien , pero si la clase fijar tiene `margin-top` negativo los elementos se van a ir mas para arriba aun , te cambie la opacidad de los `labes`(asi notas el cambio) y la correcion del `padding-left`  por `margin-left` en la clase `formulario_label`

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('formulario_input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    if(this.value.length>=1) {
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('fijar');
    } else {
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('fijar');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.formulario_label {
    margin-left: -150px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -85px;
    z-index: -20;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    transition: all 0.2s;
  }
  
 
  .fijar{
       
   margin-top:-20px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  }
```

```html
    <form action="" class="formulario">
            <h1 class="formulario_titulo">Contáctenos</h1>
            <input type="text" class="formulario_input">
                <label for="" class="formulario_label">Nombres</label>
            <input type="text" class="formulario_input">
                <label for="" class="formulario_label">Correo</label>
                </form>
```